# Migrating components not supported by eclipse

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, eclipse

How do we migrate metadata from one org to another when they are supported by metadata api but not by eclipse. The examples are sharing rules and matching rules. I have managed to migrate this from one environment to another using the metadata api but I had to manually create the metadata files for them because I cannot obtain the corresponding file from the eclipse IDE. So is there a way by which we can obtain the corresponding metadata file of components like sharing rules not supported by the force.com IDE? Thanks

Comment: Try https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/ to generate package xml and ant to migrate from one org to another.